# Is it possible to do a simple health check of RTSP stream with curl tool?

Tags: curl, rtsp

I'm trying to do a simple health check of RTSP stream with curl tool.
But command like this always gives me 404 Stream Not Found error:

```
curl -v --url rtsp://192.168.1.80/h264/ --user admin:1234
*   Trying 192.168.1.80...
* Connected to 192.168.1.80 (192.168.1.80) port 554 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0
> CSeq: 1
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> 
< RTSP/1.0 404 Stream Not Found
< CSeq: 1
< Date: Tue, Feb 27 2018 01:14:21 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.80 left intact
```

It looks like that instead of `*` it should be an URL after `OPTIONS` here:
`> OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0`

For instance, I tested the same URI with VLC media player and captured packets with tcpdump. With VLC it works without any issues and data send in request to RTSP server looks like this:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.80:554/h264 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.2 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.09)
```

It looks that there is an option `CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI` in libcurl that works under the hood of curl tool, but I can't find command line option to set this parameter so `*` is used as default value according to this: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI.html
And it doesn't automatically use value of --url neither.

Is there a way to test(a simple OK response to DESCRIBE or OPTIONS would be enough I think) RTSP stream with curl tool?

Answer (score 5):

Append `rtsp://` to the request as given below:

```
curl -v -X DESCRIBE "rtsp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@192.168.1.11:554/Streaming/Channels/101" RTSP/1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably too late to be helpful to the author of the original question, but might be useful to others. I've ran into an issue with an rtsp stream on my Laview Doorbell camera dying every couple of days, whereas camera actually stays up. A simple curl command returns options and waits for more prompt:

```
> curl -i -X OPTIONS username:userpassword@192.168.1.15:554/Streaming/Channels/101 RTSP/1.0
200 OK Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE
```

Not wanting to dive more into RTSP protocol, I tried to simply get a return status

```
> curl --head --connect-timeout 15 -i -X OPTIONS username:userpassword@192.168.1.15:554/Streaming/Channels/101
curl: (8) Weird server reply
```

This is actually different from the status of a 'dead' stream:

```
> curl --head --connect-timeout 15 -i -X OPTIONS username:userpassword@192.168.1.15:554/Streaming/Channels/101
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

This leads to this naive but functional script that restarts the camera if the status is not '8':

```
curl --head --silent --connect-timeout 15 -i -X OPTIONS username:userpassword@192.168.1.15:554/Streaming/Channels/101
if [ $? -ne 8 ]
then

 curl "http://username:userpassword@192.168.1.15/ISAPI/System/reboot" -X PUT -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.15/doc/page/config.asp" --data ""

fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use

```
curl -v -X DESCRIBE "USERNAME:PASSWORD@192.168.1.11:554/Streaming/Channels/101" RTSP/1.0
```

But it can't find the info

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.11...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.11 (192.168.1.11) port 554 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'USERNAME'
> DESCRIBE /Streaming/Channels/101 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.11:554
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
RTSP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

Seems like it's not using the right protocol ! I couldn't find how to make it use RTSP

PS : I can confirm it works with ffmpeg ! The path is right.